# Javascript image change when keydown and keyup

Tags: javascript

I have some problem regarding changing an image src when I press a key, but I can't figure it out how to do it .

I managed to change the image I have with other using `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`, and changes well, but I can't figure it out for the keys.

My project consists of controlling and rc car using raspberry pi and my website.

On the website I have 4 buttons, for directions that changes it's color when clicked on them and also there position, to simulate that it works.
But like I said in the beginning, I want to simulate the exact same thing I do with `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` using `onkeydown` and `onkeyup`, for characters `w`, `a`, `s`, `d` , because I couldn't find the ascii for the arrow keys.

Any tips are welcomed.

Comment: Sorry , i was in a haste , i can change the src from the image , not the color or background .(i have 2 images , one blue for standard , and one red to show that is being pressed or clicked)(and the buttons are img , not input types).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get any key code without google is

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',onKeydown,false);

function onKeydown(event)
{
  console.log(event.keyCode);
  switch(event.keyCode)
{
   case 38://top
           break;
   case 37://left
           break;
   case 39://right
           break;
   case 40://down
           break;
}
```

Hope this help you get the ascii for the key events :)